# C++ programming framework

Tags: c++, qt, frameworks, mfc

what are some good c++ frameworks?

i was excited with qt, i went on the page and "whoa" qt's not more nokia's product...

apparently the licence has changed and you have to share your source code to use the framework for free..

i have no problem sharing my code right now, but if in the future i want to do something close sourced i'd have to buy the licence and you have to contact them to know the price.

i was really excited, i tried MFC but it's complicated/deprecated and was looking for something that will be used in the future..

Comment: No -- you can use it [under LGPL](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Licensing/License-Comparison/), so as long as you use Qt in a DLL, you can use it for free from closed-source code.

Comment: Qt is LGPL, which means if you change Qt and use it, you need to contribute your changes **to Qt** back. You can still use it in a closed source application.

Comment: http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/newlicen.htm is another option

Comment: C++ GUI frameworks were also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157697/best-ui-development-framework-on-windows

Comment: I think [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets) is an open GUI application framework that targets roughly the same domain as Qt... Or try GTK.

Comment: .NET is free on Windows/Mac/Linux (with some limitations, since Mono is slightly behind Microsoft's .NET framework), but you'd need to pay for it on Android or iOS.

Answer (score 8):

> i was excited with qt, i went on the page and "whoa" qt's not more
>   nokia's product...

It was proprietry, then Nokia bought it, released it under joint LGPL or commercial. They have sold the commercial license to Digia

> apparently the licence has changed and you have to share your source
>   code to use the framework for free..

No it's LGPL - you have to share Qt, and any changes to Qt - not your own app.

You only need to buy a commercial licence if you want/need support from Digia.
You want to keep any changes to the Qt core you make to yourself. Or you can't install it in such a way that the Qt libs can be changed by the user (as required by the LGPL). This generally means on some embedded platform like a set-top box.

Comment: i'm not english mothertongue so i might be wrong, but i read it on the ir website

Comment: [quote]Need to secure that your software cannot be accessed or manipulated by end users[/quote]

Comment: @DomeWTF that means on platforms where the user cannot install their own software, eg embedded systems.